# i'm trying to create a search method by name but it showing this error

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

I'm very confused, I need your help, this is the error:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: single.temp] [URI: singlepost/{name}] [Missing parameter: name]. (View: C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\working\mouhawla\resources\views\index.blade.php)

The search field:

```html
<div class="search">
    <form role="form" action="{{route('single.temp')}}">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <div class="field-toggle">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The method:

```php
public function getPostByName($name) {
    $products = DB::table('templates')
        ->where('name', $name)
        ->first();

    return view('singlepost', compact('products'));
}
```

The route:

```php
Route::get('/singlepost/{name}', 'App\http\controllers\TemplatesController@getPostByName')->name('single.temp');
```

The final view:

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">ACH-template</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="/storage/{{$products->image_path}}"></td>
        <td><img src="/storage/{{$products->image_path2}}"></td>
        <td><img src="/storage/{{$products->image_path3}}"></td>
        <td>
            <p>
                <h2 style="text-align:center;">{{$products->name}}</h2>
                </br>
                <p>{{$products->description}}</p>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="/storage/{{$products->file_path}}" class="btn btn-primary">
    <button class="btn" style="width:100%">
        <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download
    </button>
</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the error? As far as I see, this does not involve HTML nor jQuery (as you haven't shared any code related to jQuery), so please either share more details about the connection, or remove these tags

Answer (score 1):

The error is very explanatory. You are trying to use `/singlepost/{name}` route, but on your blade file, you are doing `route('single.temp')`, it is telling you that it needs the parameter `name`, else it cannot create the URL as it is a missing parameter.

You should have something like:

```php
<form role="form" action="{{route('single.temp', ['name' => VALUE'])}}">
```

But that will not solve your problem, as you are trying to do a search, so you want something like `/singlepost/John`, and `John` is going to be input by the user on the `input` field. So you have to do an AJAX call because `{{ route('single.temp') }}` is going to be rendered by PHP and served to the user, so it is always going to miss the needed parameter.

What you can also do is get that value from the `Request` instead of a URL parameter.

Comment: can you give me an example if you can ?

Comment: There are plenty of good tutorials out there that had already explained this simple topic a lot of times and in more detail that I can achieve in a simple minutes. So google them, but here are some I found that could help you, some are a little more advance: [this is advanced](https://pusher.com/tutorials/laravel-vue-axios/), [here another one but simpler](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-vue-js-axios-post-request-example-and-demoexample.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a route which requires a parameter: `{$name}`. You have also used the [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route) helper to generate a `URL` which takes the name of a route as the first argument and an array of parameters as an optional second argument.

When you have used `route('single.temp')` in your form `action`, you have not specified any parameters and so Laravel is throwing the error you're seeing. To resolve this error, you would need to specify a `$name` parameter as the second argument (i.e. `route('single.temp', ['name' => 'something'])`). This is not ideal though as if you're using `$name` as a search term, you don't know the value when the page is first rendered and so can't provide that value.

There are a few ways you could achieve your goal of searching records, a basic example of how you could do this follows.

**web.php**

Define two routes, the first to return a view with a form and another to process the form submission and show the results.

```php
Route::get('/templates', [TemplateController::class, 'index'])
        ->name('templates.index');
Route::get('/templates/search', [TemplateController::class, 'search')
        ->name('templates.search');
```

**TemplateController.php**

Define the two functions which will be used when one of the routes defined above is requested.

```php
class TemplateController extends Controller
{
    // return a view
    public function index()
    {
        return view('templates.search', ['templates' => []]);
    }

    // process the form submission
    // perform a search for the $request search term
    // return a view with the results
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'term' => ['required', 'string']
        ]);

        $templates = Template::where('name', $request->term)->get();

        return view('templates.search', ['templates' => $templates]);
    }
}
```

**templates/search.blade.php**

```html
{{-- create a form which will submit to the search route --}}
{{-- note I use GET rather than POST here, explained later --}}
<form action="{{ route('templates.search') }}" method="GET">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" id="term" name="term" />
    <button type="submit">
        {{ __('Search') }}
    </button>

    {{-- loop over and show results if there are any --}}
    @forelse ($templates as $template)
        {{ $template->name }}
    @empty
        {{ __('Empty') }}
    @endforelse
</form>
```

The above should be self explanatory. My reason for using `GET` rather than `POST` in the `search` is because the value will be added to the `URL` as a query string parameter meaning it can be bookmarked or shared with ease.